# VBA Loop That Runs External Macro Within All Files in Folder

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am running the following code which is intended to loop through multiple workbooks, run a macro on each, close and save each. However, it stops after running through the first file within the folder. Any thoughts as to why it is not recognizing the other files? No error message populates.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenRunCode()

Const sPath = "\\drive\folder\"
Dim sFil As String
Dim owb As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sFil = Dir(sPath & "*File.xlsm")

Do While sFil <> ""
    Set owb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFil)
        Application.Run ("'" + sFil + "'!Macro")
        owb.Save
        owb.Close
    sFil = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you want to save and close `owb` before opening the next file?

Comment: The Save and Close owb is part of the Macro. So no need for an additional Save Close

Comment: Can I see the macro?

Comment: The macro that closes the workbook doesn't find an end because the workbook it's in is closed before it finishes. Move the closing of owb to the master procedure and the problem should disappear.

Comment: As a matter of principle: Always close a workbook in the same procedure where you opened it.

Comment: Thank you all! Adding the Save and Close within the Master Macro worked.